# Google Maps Direction API response not mapping with road

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, google-cloud-platform, google-directions-api

I am trying to call directions API and showing the route on Map, but the route is not perfectly matching the road.

[image: Screenshot of map with polyline]

Here's how I am getting Directions:

```
suspend fun getGoogleDirections(
    origin: LatLng,
    destination: LatLng,
    mapsApiKey: String
): Flow<DataState<List<LatLng>>> = flow {

    try {
        val apiResponse = apiInterface.getDirectionFromGoogle(
            "${origin.latitude},${origin.longitude}",
            "${destination.latitude},${destination.longitude}",
            mapsApiKey
        )

        if (apiResponse.isSuccessful) {
            val responseBody = apiResponse.body()!!
            logD(TAG, "response = ${responseBody}")

            val responseObject = JSONObject(responseBody)
            val routes = responseObject.getJSONArray("routes")
            val firstRoute = routes.getJSONObject(0)
            val legs = firstRoute.getJSONArray("legs")
            val firstLeg = legs.getJSONObject(0)
            val steps = firstLeg.getJSONArray("steps")

            val ovPolyline = firstRoute.getJSONObject("overview_polyline")
            val polyline = ovPolyline.getString("points")

            emit(DataState.Success(PolyUtil.decode(polyline)))
        } else {
            val error = apiResponse.errorBody()?.string()!!
            logE(TAG,"",  error)
            emit(DataState.Error("error in fetching directions"))
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        logE(TAG,"",e.message ?: "Exception")
        emit(DataState.Error("An unexpected error occurred"))
    }

}
```

My API interface:

```
@GET("directions/json")
suspend fun getDirectionFromGoogle(
    @Query("origin") origin: String,
    @Query("destination") destination: String,
    @Query("key") apiKey: String,
    @Query("mode") mode: String = "driving"
): Response<String>
```

Adding Polyline on Map

```
val directionPolyline = mMap.addPolyline(
                    PolylineOptions()
                        .color(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.colorPrimaryDark))
                        //.width(3f)
                        .geodesic(false)
                        .endCap(RoundCap())
                        .startCap(RoundCap())
                        .addAll(listOfPoints)
                )
```

I face this problem specially if the distance is large. For nearby distance the results are still better.

Note: Earlier I have used MapBox and in that there is a key "overview=full" that Enables this but I am not able to find anything in Google Maps.

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of google maps. Api does not provide the full number of Point. Hence our lines deviate from the map.

If Google Api provided us with more points, then the route could be displayed like this
[image]